# Printing from Amazon VPC Windows Remote Desktop Server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, amazon-web-services, remote-desktop-services, printing

I spun up a Remote Desktop Server instance on Amazon's Virtual Private Cloud service...  What's the best/easiest way to print from the VPC to local printers?

The local printers are IP based, but not "cloud printers".

I'm familiar with how Cloud Printing works for Chrome, but is there a way to install a cloud printer as a regular Windows printer on a Remote Desktop Server and "just have it work?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed the SonicWALL Global VPN Client on a MS Server 2008 R2 File and Print server, connected the client to the local SonicWALL, and then installed the local printers on the remote print server and deployed them via Group Policy.

This solution will work for legacy printers until I can replace them with "cloud enabled" printers.

Comment: This sounds like a lot pieces, to my ears. Why not just make the printers visible as lpr devices or such? This is a sonicwall specific solution, and is not generally useful.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, if you can connect to server instance on VPC via RDP, then just configure local resources like printer\disks to be mapped to the remote server in RDP window and when print as usual.
You may need also to install printer drivers on the remote host for this feature to work.

Comment: That's a great quick and dirty solution, but instead of accessing the full desktop, the users are only accessing remote apps through an RDP to HTML5 web browser interface.  While the app supports local printers, I don't want to have to manage local printer installs on their local machines.